# iOSOpenDev Including Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, jailbreak, theos

I am trying to use iOSOpenDev to build a jailbreak tweak. I am used to doing everything in programmatically and without using interface builder. I want add a background to my UIButton by doing this.

```
button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I run the code on my iPhone, the background image is not displayed. I have the image in the same directory as my tweak.xm file. How would I give the UIButton a background of this image? I would easily be able to in a regular application by adding it to the project assets, but there isn't one in the Logos template.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have the image in the same directory as my tweak.xm file." - that's the problem. `imageNamed:` searches files in the app bundle.

Comment: How would I add the image to the app bundle?

Comment: @TaylorJiggly, you said you're not building an **app**.  You're building a **tweak**.  Which app, or library, is the tweak injected into?  SpringBoard?  Something else?  That defines where `imageNamed:` will look.

Comment: @Nate I have my tweak injected into the springboard. On launch, my UIWindow is displayed and I have a button that I want to set the image for.

Comment: It the tweak is injected into SpringBoard, then `imageNamed:` will look in the SpringBoard.app bundle.  You probably should have your images stored somewhere else, and then load them with `-[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` instead.

Comment: @Nate Where would I place this line of code? I tried placing it inside the hook block and it said "Expected Selector for Objective-c method". I believe that this might have something to do with the "-" in front of the code.

Comment: I can't tell you where to put it.  You need to put it in code that runs when you want to load the image.  I don't know how you want your application to work.  You can create a hook block to hook into any function.   If you've tried something new, use the **edit** link under the question to add more information to your question.  Don't delete the question text you have now.  Just add more information on what code you added that gave you the error message.